# html class names... but not really?

Tags: html, class

Looking at the sourcecode for a website i see in th html tag all this stuff in the class tag

```
  class=" yui3-js-enabled
      js
      flexbox
      canvas
      canvastext
      webgl
      no-touch
      hashchange
      history
      draganddrop
      rgba
      hsla
      multiplebgs
      backgroundsize
      borderimage
      borderradius
      boxshadow
      textshadow
      opacity
      cssanimations
      csscolumns
      cssgradients
      cssreflections
      csstransforms
      no-csstransforms3d
      csstransitions
      video
      audio
      svg
      inlinesvg
      svgclippaths
      wf-futurapt-n4-active
      wf-futurapt-n5-active
      wf-bebaskai-n4-active
      wf-futurapt-n7-active
      wf-hypatiasanspro-n2-active
      wf-hypatiasanspro-n4-active
      wf-hypatiasanspro-n6-active
      wf-hypatiasanspro-n7-active
      wf-futurapt-i4-active
      wf-futurapt-n3-active
      wf-futurapt-i5-active
      wf-futurapt-i7-active wf-active"
```

what on earth is all this stuff? is it necessary?

For example, I know what rgba is in terms of using it for say a background like

```
#p1 {background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.3);} /* red with opacity*/
```

but what does it do if you just put

```
<html class="rgba">
```

Comment: What is is: Classnames. Is it necessary: maybe, there is a few million ways to solve something this might be one. What does it do: use the developer tools and find out.

Comment: That's what happens when you leave it to AI to design a website. Seriously though, in your example of `class = "rgba"`, what would happen would be dependent on the `rgba` class definitions. e.g., `.rgba { width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;}`

Answer (score 2):

Many of those are just marker classes indicating browser support for various features.

These classes get added by javascript that does tests on page load to see what features are supported in this particular browser.

This allows the page or app to adapt to the environment it's in. For example, you might have css rules that style a component differently on the basis of whether flexbox is supported:

```css
html.flexbox .myComponent { 
  display: flex; /* flex supported. use it. */
}

html:not(.flexbox) .myComponent {
  display: block; /* no flex support. do something else. */
}
```